# Keeping Uploaded Images On Page After Refresh (PHP/HTML/JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I'm doing a small project where I'm trying to create a continual gallery for a user; whereby, they upload a file, and it immediately appears on the same page. The one thing I can't manage to accomplish is to keep the files there on the page even if the page is refreshed. In other words, I want the user to return and see all of their uploaded files as if they never left, until they close the browser. I've tried using cookies and session variables but I'm confused on how to implement this. Here is my Code. I APOLOGIZE IN ADVANCE FOR BAD INDENTATION.

```
My index.php:
  <?php
  // Process image

  $uploadName = 'uploaded/pic.jpg';

  if (count($_FILES))
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadName);
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            li { display: inline-block; padding: 200px; width: 200px;}
            img { width: 100%; height:100%;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function iframeSubmit(formElem, action, callback) {

                // name a callback that will be called from inside the iframe
                var callbackName = 'iframe' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000);

                action = action + (action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'callback='+         

                callbackName;

                // create an iframe and use the callback as its name 
                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.setAttribute('name', callbackName);
                iframe.style.display = 'none';

                // add the target and edit the action of the form
                formElem.setAttribute('target', callbackName);
                formElem.setAttribute('action', action);

                // add the hidden iframe after the form
                formElem.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);

                window[callbackName] = callback;
            }
            ;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload()">


        <a href="index.php" class="menu_link">Home</a>
        <a href="Schedule.html" class="menu_link">Schedule</a>
        <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image"/>
            <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <?php if (count($_FILES)): ?>

                <li><img src="<?php echo $uploadName ?>"/></li>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onload() {

            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function processResponse(response) {
                if (!response.success) {
                    alert('woopsie');
                    return;
                }

                var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
                newListItem.innerHTML = '<img src="' + response.path + '"/>';

                document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].appendChild(newListItem);


            }

            function onload() {

                iframeSubmit(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0], 'upload.php',                                
            processResponse);



            }

         </script>
     </body>
  </html>

  Here is my upload.php:

  <?php

    enter code here

  $imagePath = 'uploaded/pic.jpg';
  setcookie("cookie", "stuff", time() + 3600, $uploadName);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imagePath);
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>Iframe content</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
   echo 'window.parent[\'' . $_GET['callback'] . '\']('
   . json_encode(array('success' => true, 'path' => $imagePath)) . ')';
  ?>


        </script>


     </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: iframe your upload so the page does not refresh and get the response to be caught by javascript or php on main page

Comment: how exactly do I 'catch' a response?